# User settings not loading/saving

Tags: c#, settings, application-settings

I am having this problem with loading/saving application settings. I am saving the settings like this

```
    string value = "test";
    Properties.Settings.Default.test1 = value;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

It works if I load the settings while the program is still running but whenever I close the application and start it up again the saved value is gone.

```
    string savedValue = Properties.Settings.Default.test1;
```

I have tried Refreshing after saving but that does not seem to help.

However I found where the settings are stored (Appdata\Local) and the value indeed shows up in there but it does not get loaded.

Comment: The settings file used won't be the same in debug/release mode. The same goes for when you run it stand-alone or in VS.

Comment: Does the Settings.settings file show up in the solution under the Properties folder?

Comment: @Micke I build it in debug mode but I am not running it through the debugger.

Comment: As long as you run the exact same app, it should work. That is, you cannot save a setting in the debugger and try to read it outside VS.

Comment: You are not accessing the settings from another thread?

Comment: @Micke No, it is the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it is done. If your code doesn't work, try creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to enable further debugging.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This should be blank on first run, but not on subsequent: {0}", Properties.Settings.Default.test1);

            string value = "test";

            Properties.Settings.Default.test1 = value;

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Pass #1:**

```
This should be blank on first run, but not on subsequent:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Pass #2:**

```
This should be blank on first run, but not on subsequent: test
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This is what I am doing but it will give me an empty string.

Comment: Same problem here... What's more, some string settings are saved and some are not. Consistently. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Having the file user.config open in the IDE, I get prompted to reload it just when `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` was executed, i.e., the file is being written to disk, but does not include all values.

Comment: Do you have the scope set to User? Application settings cannot be changed at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I am a WPF Developer , so am sure that the Properties.Settings definitely save while use

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Or

```
Properties.Settings settings= new Properties.Settings();
settings.YourParameter=true;
settings.Save();
```

If you don't get the updated value in settings then you first use 
settings=new Properties.Settings();
You will be definitely get new result.